# How do i remove string if and only if end of string using r programming

Tags: r, regex

I want to remove Bangalore from list of strings and Bangalore should be end of the string in the list.

**Input data:**

```
TCS bangalore
Wipro global Bangalore
Bangalore consultant India private limited
Infosys Bangalore
systems bangalore pvt ltd
```

**Expected Output data:**

```
TCS
Wipro global
Bangalore consultant India private limited
Infosys
systems bangalore pvt ltd
```

Help me to get expected output in R programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sub` in case insensitive mode:

```
output <- sub("\\s+Bangalore$", "", input, ignore.case=TRUE)
output

[1] "TCS"                                       
[2] "Wipro global"                              
[3] "Bangalore consultant India private limited"
[4] "Infosys"                                   
[5] "systems bangalore pvt ltd"
```

**Data:**

```
input <- c("TCS bangalore",
           "Wipro global Bangalore",
           "Bangalore consultant India private limited",
           "Infosys Bangalore",
           "systems bangalore pvt ltd")
```

Comment: And if you wish to ignore white space at the end of the string, you could modify with `output <- sub("\\s+Bangalore$", "", trimws(input), ignore.case=TRUE)`

Comment: @Benjamin The replacement being done by my answer shouldn't leave behind any rogue trailing whitespace.  The `\s+` before `Bangalore` takes care of that.

Comment: We might be talking about two separate things.  Try using `"Wipro global Banaglore    "` in `input` and compare the result.

Comment: OK...then I agree with you.  I guess I never copied over the trailing whitespace.

Comment: I don't think there was any trailing whitespace in the input provided.  It's just the kind of thing I've been bit in the butt by so many times that I've become sensitized to it. :)

Comment: if you don't mind i would like to extend the question.. if i have multiple names which i would like to replace if it is end of the string. How could i do that. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @GuruS If you have a very small extension, feel free to ask here.  Otherwise, consider opening a new question.

Comment: if i have multiple names which i would like to replace if it is end of the string. How could i do that. Also i want to filter data multiple names if it is in particular column in dataframe

Comment: For multiple names, use something like: `sub("\\s+(?:Bangalore|Chennai|Hyderabad)$", "", input, ignore.case=TRUE)` ... for your other question, you should open a new question.